# Dependencies not working when running ASP.NET Core 1.0 website on .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In my solution I have the following projects

**Solution 'NewCo'**

- NewCo.DataAccess *(Class Library, .NET 4.6.1)*
- NewCo.DomainModel *(Class Library, .NET 4.6.1)*
- NewCo.IdentityModel *(Class Library, .NET 4.6.1)*
- NewCo.Website *(ASP.NET Core Web Application, .NET 4.6.1)*

And here is a snippet from my *project.json* file showing the frameworks and dependencies

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "net461"
        ],
        "dependencies": {
            "NewCo.DataAccess": {
                "target": "project"
            },
            "NewCo.DomainModel": {
                "target": "project"
            },
            "NewCo.IdentityModel": {
                "target": "project"
            }
        }
    }
  },
```

When I try referencing these dependencies, I don't seem to have access to them:

```
using NewCo... // intellisense only show me ".Website"
```

Why can't I reference my `DataAccess`, `DomainModel` or `IdentityModel` dependencies?

Comment: Does the project actually build despite this?  In other words, is this just a tooling issue vs code is borked issue?  I noticed a lot of issues with intellisense lately but the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, No it didn't build, but check out my answer which outlines my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I found a good solution.

My project consists of some classic .NET class libraries being referenced by an ASP.NET Core web application, targeting `.NET 4.6.1`, and referencing `NETStandardLibrary 1.6.0`

**The Problem**

References to the classic .NET class libraries don't work

**The Solution**

1. Port the classic .NET class libraries to .NET Core class libraries
2. target `.NET 4.6.1` across all projects and reference `NETStandardLibrary 1.6.0` across all projects
3. Where applicable, reference nuget packages in class libraries *(in my case this was entity framework 6.1.3 and Microsoft Identity Framework for Entity Framework)*
4. Reference the .NET Core class libraries in the ASP.NET Core application

It worked well for me. I hope, if you find this, that it works for you to!